# Why is 'method not found' appearing when using Resourceful controller?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to create a restful api with Laravel 4 but all the time I get an error:

> "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException","message":"Controller method not found."

I follow the explanation on [routes-first-in-first-out](http://laravel.io/topic/30/routes-first-in-first-out). But I had no luck.

My routes looks like:

```php
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
    Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');
});

Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

And the method in the controller looks like

```php
public function store()
{
 // ... somecode       
}
```

And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I already search here but I keep having the same result.

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: What URLs are you attempting which don't work? Note that [resourceful controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) come with a specific schema of how they map to specific methods in the controller, including taking HTTP method into account (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE). See the table in the link above.

Comment: Which URL are you hitting?

Comment: The `store` function will only be _found_ when doing a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn more about Restful Controllers first. If you look closely on the [docs page](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers), on the table there..

your action `store` says:

```
Verb    Path        Action  Route Name
POST    /resource   store   resource.store
```

which means:

1. store can only be triggered when using a POST request (the `verb` on the table above).
2. the `path` is /resource, in your case `api/v1/contact`
3. if you are going to redirect to it using a named route, you will use the route name (ex: Redirect::route('api/v1/contact.create') goes to add page) *Note: redirecting to store would make no sense so i used create instead*

Back to your question..

Going via the browser with a URL of 'api/v1/contact/store' will produce a GET request
to that route, but store expects a POST request. if you submit a POST from a form to the store URL, it will succeed but going to it via browser(GET) will surely produce an error saying the route cannot be found since you don't have a get 'api/v1/contact/store' route declared..

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself with clarity. But, yes I'm trying to rich the store method with a post request done with js. And I send some data as json.I tryed to change the method name to postStore and the result was the same. `code` $http( {
                         url: '/api/v1/contact',
                         method: 'POST',
                         data: p
                     }).success( function( response ){
                         def.resolve( response );
                     });`code`

Comment: when I tryed to use url /api/v1/contact/store I get the method not allowed exception. I don't know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

I found that after the post request that i made originally with javascript, that a redirect is triggerso taht it fails.
I don't know why. The .htacces file is the original from laravel intalation and the virtual host is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName raulcm.laravel
        DocumentRoot /var/www/raulcm.laravel/public
        <Directory /var/www/raulcm.laravel/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/raulcm.laravel/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/raulcm.laravel/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: check my latest comment, and this should have been a comment or edit on your question as it is not an answer. ;)